# Unity running post construction routine

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is there a way to tell Unity DI Container to run a certain routine after it finished constructing the object?

The idea is that I want Unity to handle object construction, but then afterwards complement the constructed object with a set of my own routines. So unlike `InjectionFactory` where I have to basically take over object construction, I want Unity to run its job first before plugging in.

Comment: Can you post an example use case how would a customization look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `InjectionMethod` if the initialization logic is in the same class:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Initialize_should_get_called_on_object_construction()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IDependency, Dependency>(
            new InjectionMethod("Initialize" /*, parameters if present */)
        );

        var dependency = container.Resolve<IDependency>();

        Assert.IsNotNull(dependency);
        Assert.AreEqual("init", dependency.Value);
    }
}

public interface IDependency
{
    string Value { get; set; }
    void Initialize();
}

public class Dependency : IDependency 
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public void Initialize() {
        this.Value = "init";
    }
}
```

If not, you're gonna need to create an *abstract factory* to do the job.

Comment: Yep, this would be the way to go. Be aware that if the injection method has parameters, the container will resolve those parameters as well, just like it does for constructor parameters.